# How do I use the variable distanceHala outside of this public void?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, location

So what I want is to calculate the distance between the users current location and a marker on the map.

```
    final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            if (locationResult == null) {
                return;
            }
            mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
            final double distanceHala = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);
            mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
        }
    };
```

So this is the code I have right now to calculate the distance. I'm not sure if this would work. Now I want to use the variable distanceHala in an if statement to activate an Onclicklistener:

```
else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal A")) {
                      if (distanceHala < 10){
                        Intent halaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, hala.class);
                        startActivity(halaIntent);}}
```

This is what I have for that.
The problem is that it doesn't recognise the variable distanceHala.
This is my first project working with Android Studio and Java, so explain it like I'm 12.

Full Code:

```
package com.example.discoverkoelak;

import ...

public class MapS extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    private List<AutocompletePrediction> predictionList;

    private Location mLastKnownLocation;
    private LocationCallback locationCallback;
    private final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 18;



    private View mapView;
    private Marker kaka;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.MapS);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MapS.this);
        Places.initialize(MapS.this, ("MY API KEY"));
        ImageView legendeBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.merkar);
        legendeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent maptoLegende = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activity_legende.class);
                startActivity(maptoLegende);
            }
        });





        final AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 51) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        }


    }
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (mLastKnownLocation != null) {
                                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            } else {
                                final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                                locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
                                locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
                                locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                                locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                                        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                                        if (locationResult == null) {
                                            return;
                                        }
                                        mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                                        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
                                    }
                                };
                                mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null);

                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MapS.this, "Laatste gekende locatie kan niet worden ontvangen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }



    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {





        int height = 120;
        int width = 90;
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_dark);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw2=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_aula_0);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw3=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_research_0);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw4=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_residentie);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw5=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_ontspanning);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw6=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_mobiliteit_1);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw7=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_research_1);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw8=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_mobiliteit_0);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw9=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_administratie);


        Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b2=bitmapdraw2.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b3=bitmapdraw3.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b4=bitmapdraw4.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b5=bitmapdraw5.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b6=bitmapdraw6.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b7=bitmapdraw7.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b8=bitmapdraw8.getBitmap();
        Bitmap b9=bitmapdraw9.getBitmap();
        Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
        Bitmap aulas = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b2, width, height, false);
        Bitmap research = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b3, width, height, false);
        Bitmap residenties = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b4, width, height, false);
        Bitmap ontspanning = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b5, width, height, false);
        Bitmap mobiliteitU = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b6, width, height, false);
        Bitmap researchU = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b7, width, height, false);
        Bitmap mobiliteit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b8, width, height, false);
        Bitmap administratie = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b9, width, height, false);
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


Here I give all the markers their coordinates



        //Code die markers zet en ze klikbaar maakt.
        //Hal A
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HalA)
                .title("Hal A")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal A")) {
                      Intent halaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, hala.class);
                      startActivity(halaIntent);
                      return false;
                  }
                  return false;
              }
          }
        );

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stuvo)
                .title("Stuvo")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bib)
                .title("Bib")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(acco)
                .title("Acco boekenhandel")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(rectoraat)
                .title("Hal Rectoraat")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(administratie)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(spina)
                .title("Spina")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mobiliteit)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(stilleRuimte)
                .title("Stille ruimte")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(A301)
                .title("Aula Stijn Streuvels (A301)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(weetkelder)
                .title("Weetkelder")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(researchU)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fietsena)
                .title("FietsenA")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mobiliteitU)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(labos)
                .title("Labo's (gang 3)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));


        //gebouw B
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(B422)
                .title("B422")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));


        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(puc)
                .title("puc")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        //gebouw c
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(C611)
                .title("C611")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(gang7)
                .title("Gang 7")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        //gebouw E
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(E1001)
                .title("Aula Andreas Vesalius (E1001)")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(aulas)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vaardigheidscentrum)
                .title("Vaardigheidscentrum")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(IRF)
                .title("IRF")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fietsene)
                .title("fietsene")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mobiliteitU)));

        //residenties
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(spoelberg)
                .title("Spoelberg")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(residenties)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(studentendorp)
                .title("Studentendorp")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(residenties)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(corona)
                .title("Corona")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(residenties)));

        //andere
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(IICK)
                .title("IICK")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(research)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(almaZweetkelder)
                        .title("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ecolab)
                .title("Ecolab")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(ontspanning)));

        //Afstand berekenen tussen laatst gekende locatie en PoI's
//        LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
//        final double distanceEcolab = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, ecolab);
//        final double distanceHala = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);

        final LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                if (locationResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                mLastKnownLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                final double distanceHala = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);
                mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
            }
        };



        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                  if (marker.getTitle().equals("Ecolab")) {
                      Intent ecolabIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_ecolab.class);
                      startActivity(ecolabIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Alma & Cantor en Zweetkelder")) {
                      Intent AlmaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acz.class);
                      startActivity(AlmaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("IICK")) {
                      Intent IICKIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_iick.class);
                      startActivity(IICKIntent);

                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Corona")) {
                      Intent coronaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_corona.class);
                      startActivity(coronaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Studentendorp")){
                      Intent studentendorpIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_studentendorp.class);
                      startActivity(studentendorpIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Spoelberg")) {
                      Intent spoelbergIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_spoelberg.class);
                      startActivity(spoelbergIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("fietsene")) {
                      Intent fietseneIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_fietsene.class);
                      startActivity(fietseneIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("IRF")) {
                      Intent IRFIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_irf.class);
                      startActivity(IRFIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Vaardigheidscentrum")) {
                      Intent vaardigheidscentrumIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_vaardigheid.class);
                      startActivity(vaardigheidscentrumIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Aula Andreas Vesalius (E1001)")) {
                      Intent E1001Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_e1001.class);
                      startActivity(E1001Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Gang 7")) {
                      Intent gang7Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_kantoren.class);
                      startActivity(gang7Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("C611")) {
                      Intent C611Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_c611.class);
                      startActivity(C611Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("puc")) {
                      Intent pucIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_puc.class);
                      startActivity(pucIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("B422")) {
                      Intent B422Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_b422.class);
                      startActivity(B422Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Labo's (gang 3)")) {
                      Intent labosIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_labo.class);
                      startActivity(labosIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("FietsenA")) {
                      Intent fietsenaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_fietsena.class);
                      startActivity(fietsenaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Weetkelder")) {

//                      LatLng lastKnownLatLng = new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
//                      final double distanceWeet = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);
//                      if (distanceWeet < 20) {
                      Intent weetkelderIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_weetkelder.class);
                      startActivity(weetkelderIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Aula Stijn Streuvels (A301)")) {
                      Intent A301Intent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_A301.class);
                      startActivity(A301Intent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Stille ruimte")) {
                      Intent stilIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_stil.class);
                      startActivity(stilIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Spina")) {
                      Intent spinaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_spina.class);
                      startActivity(spinaIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal Rectoraat")) {
                      Intent rectoraatIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_rectoraat.class);
                      startActivity(rectoraatIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Acco boekenhandel")) {
                      Intent accoIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_acco.class);
                      startActivity(accoIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Bib")) {
                      Intent bibIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_onthaalbib.class);
                      startActivity(bibIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Stuvo")) {
                      Intent stuvoIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, activity_secstuvo.class);
                      startActivity(stuvoIntent);
                  }

                  else if (marker.getTitle().equals("Hal A")) {
                      if (distanceHala < 10){
                        Intent halaIntent = new Intent(MapS.this, hala.class);
                        startActivity(halaIntent);}}
                  return true;
              }
          }
        );













        if(mapView != null && mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null)  {
            View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) locationButton.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            layoutParams.setMargins(0,0,40,180);

        }

        // kijken of gps signaal aanstaat
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(MapS.this);
        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
        task.addOnSuccessListener(MapS.this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(MapS.this, new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if(e instanceof  ResolvableApiException) {
                    ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                    try{
                    resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MapS.this, 51);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }}





        );


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so what you want to do is make your variable a global variable in your class, so that other methods can access it.
Just below this line:

`public class MapS extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {`

Add a line:
`private final double distanceHala;`

Then, go to the line you give distanceHala a value:

`final double distanceHala =SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);`

and change it to:-
`distanceHala =SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(lastKnownLatLng, HalA);`

And thats it, it should work. 
If it doesn't, do let me know :)

Comment: So it seems like it would work, no nullpointer errors and it recognises the variable, only it's still clickable when I'am further away than the distance I declared.

Comment: Use the final declaration, that I just edited the line to. If that doesn't work, try setting the default activity to not clickable.

Comment: Get an error if I add the final to that line, and normally the default should be not clickable. When I tried to resolve the error and try to initialize distanceHala as 0, I still get an error when I try to overwrite it with the actual distance. The error I get then is "Canot assign a value to final variable 'distanceHala'

Comment: btw, doesn't the 'final' mean that it can't change anymore? If that's the case, I need it to not be 'final' because the distance changes everytime I check the users current location